# R: Embedding #comments in the middle of a command

Tags: comments, hashtag

I'm using R, though I'd imagine this applies to some other languages as well. I'm trying to embed `#comments` in the middle of a single command to be executed. The problem is that `#` takes everything till the end of the line as irrelevant comments. Is there some symbol that negates `#` and makes the line executable again?

Ex.:

`gsub('x', #comment1,'y', #comment2, 'axe')
[1] "aye"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but you need to ensure that your comments are at the end of a split command.

For example:

```
test = c('1', # this is one 
         '2', # this is another one 
         '3'  # and yet another one 
) 
test
```

Note that the commas here (before the comments) are interpreted to expect more content.  I.e. the command isn't finished. The rest of the command is then looked at on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. There aren't any operators in R that denote the end of comment section. In other languages you can have a start `/*` and end `*/` but it doesn't look like R supports such a thing, it just looks for the end of line to terminate the comment.

In general, such a thing is considered bad practice (as it makes code less readable, which is the opposite of what you want). Consider placing the comments above or below the line to describe the variables.

Wish I had a better answer for you. :(

Comment: that's kinda what i expected. no worries, i've figured out a work around :)

Comment: This is possible, but you need to ensure that your comments are at the end of a split command.  For example:

    test = c('1', # this is one
             '2', # this is another one
             '3'  # and yet another one
             )
    test

Note that the commas here specify that the command isn't finished.  The rest of the command is then looked at on the next line.

Comment: Good to hear! Happy coding!